# Can I define the celery queue property on a Task at runtime?

Tags: django, celery

Use case:

```
class MyTask(Task):
    queue = 'default_queue'

    def run(self):
        # do work
```

Normally I would run the following which would use the 'default_queue' specified.

```
MyTask.delay()
```

What I need to do is something like:

```
if hours_since_last_login > 24:
    MyTask.delay()   # using the queue 'high_priority_queue'
else:
    MyTask.delay()   # using the 'default_queue'
```

I know I can subclass MyTask to override the `queue` property, but is there a way to define it at runtime?

Is this the following the correct way to do it?

```
task = MyTask()
task.queue = 'high_priority_queue'
task.delay()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From askol on IRC:

```
MyTask.apply_async(args=[], kwargs={}, queue='high_priority_queue')
```